# Defining codition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is what the source XML document for the transformation below could look like (reverse-engineered and provided by Dimitre):

```
<Provider Identifier="1P">
  <Identifications>
    <Identification>
     <Value>1013977438</Value>
     <Type>Z86</Type>
    </Identification>
    <Identification>
     <Value>1013977438</Value>
     <Type>HPI</Type>
    </Identification>
    <Identification>
     <Type>HPI</Type>
    </Identification>
  </Identifications>
</Provider>
```

My XSLT code is:

```
<xsl:template match="Identifications">
    <xsl:if test="/Provider/Identifications/Identification/Value!=''">
        <Identifications>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Provider/Identifications/*">
                <Identification>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Identification>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Identifications>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But my desire output is:

```
<Provider Identifier="1P">
  <Identifications>
    <Identification Value="1013977438" Type="Z86"/>
    <Identification Value="1013977438" Type="HPI"/>
  </Identifications>
</Provider>
```

Now what is the condition should i apply in above XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not a truly xlst one. You might try changing the template to something like the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Identifications">
        <Identifications>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="*[./Value!='']"/>
        </Identifications>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Identification">
                <Identification>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Identification>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:apply-templates`. Then you won't need the second template (which doesn't do anything other than a convoluted copy).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I was more tempted replacing the remaining for-each by another level of template. Just for illustrating basic principle of xlst processing. Using copy-of would at have led to a nasty expression that would not have been understood easily by OP. But, I suggest you add such solution as another answer, for illustrating a much less verbose and more compact way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:  You might have noticed that the XML shown is the **output** of the transformation, not the input. The original XSL is using `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>`- hardly anything that refers to attributes. You have to reverse engeneer the input from output and script given.

Answer (score 3):

All provided answers are unnecessarily complex.

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Identification[not(@Value)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Update**:

Initially I thought that the OP provided his source XML document. Now I see that this is actually the *result* of his transformation.

**I had to reverse-engineer what the actual source XML could be**. Something like this:

```
<Provider Identifier="1P">
  <Identifications>
    <Identification>
     <Value>1013977438</Value>
     <Type>Z86</Type>
    </Identification>
    <Identification>
     <Value>1013977438</Value>
     <Type>HPI</Type>
    </Identification>
    <Identification>
     <Type>HPI</Type>
    </Identification>
  </Identifications>
</Provider>
```

Again, there is a simpler solution than offered in the rest of the answers:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Identification[Value]/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Identification[not(Value)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

- Start with Identity transform
- Have template for Identification with Value attribute not empty
  `<xsl:template match="Identification[@Value!='']">`
- An a template to ignore all other Identification
  `<xsl:template match="Identification" />`

Therefore:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">      

      <!-- Identity transform -->
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Identification[@Value!='']">
        <Identification>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Identification>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Identification" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```